# Check if a location on a leaflet map is a marker or not

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to determine if there already is a marker at a certain lat and lng

The only method I found when doing research was `mymap.hasLayer(marker)`

But I don't want to and can't use a marker variable since I only have the location (lat, long)

I need to know this because some markers will overlap and the only way I know how to solve that is check if a marker exists on that location and if it does the modify it add info to it

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the layers on the map, and check each marker.

```
var targeLatLng = L.latLng(lat, lng);

map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            if (layer.getLatLng() === targetLatLng) {


            // We found a marker at the target lat, lng

         }
    });
```

You might want to use `layer.getLatLng().distanceTo(targetLatLng) < something` if you need a minimum distance apart rather than exact equality.